# Vue 2.0 rendering problem it's setting div id="1" when I'm actually providing a different id

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I'm encountering this problem lately with a Vue v2.0 application. Whenever, it re-compiles the project it turns this

```
<div id="NewGroupManager"></div>
```

into this

```
<div id="1"></div>
```

**Note**: This div is right inside the `<template></template>` tags.

So, it completely messes up the style. But if I add a new id name, it works again for a while and then it goes back to setting id="1". I don't know if this is because of my device, I'm running macOS and I recently upgraded to Big Sur, before this it never happened.

I'm using .less FYI.

Comment: When you refer to style is about your CSS, if this is the case, I recommend you to base your CSS practices on classes, not ids.
Apply BEM can be a good practice.

Comment: @jc.vargas.valencia That doesn't solve the issue though. The problem is the id not the CSS.